# How to deploy a React website via Vercel or Surge?

Tags: html, reactjs, deployment, vercel, surge.sh

Although it seems like I was able to deploy the website successfully (which was built with React), as soon as I click on the deployed link, the browser takes me back to localhost:3000. I assume it's because I've set redirectUri as the following `const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/callback/";`, but I am not sure howelse I could set the redirectUri. Can someone help me with this issue please?

Here is the surge link : [www.spotify_playlist_jammming.surge.sh](http://www.spotify_playlist_jammming.surge.sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `redirectUri` to a callback route in `http://www.spotify_playlist_jammming.surge.sh`

Comment: I've updated it following your suggestion, but still the same issue is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "VERCEL_URL" as an environment variable: https://vercel.com/docs/v2/build-step#system-environment-variables

You can then use something like `REACT_APP_URL=$VERCEL_URL`